# C++ - LoadString() inside win32 DLL does not work

Tags: c++, winapi, dll, resources

So I have a win32 DLL with a tbl.rc file containing the following code:

```
STRINGTABLE
BEGIN
   1 "Hola!"
END
```

And in my DLLMain, I am doing something like this

```
char* strt = new char[5];
LoadString(hinstDLL, 1, strt, 5); // "hinstDLL" is a parameter passed by DLLMain, which SHOULD be the HINSTANCE of the DLL
printf("String is %s", strt);
```

However, my output is **always**

```
String is
```

And I would like to know why and how to fix it, of course. Thank you very much!

Comment: Try googling "null-terminated string".  Also, the documentation for `LoadString` explains how to determine why it failed.

Comment: "Hola!" has 6 characters, forgetting about the zero terminator is a standard bug.  Not checking for errors is another one.

Comment: Even if I up it to 6 it doesn't work :/

Comment: Check the return value of `LoadString`. If it is zero, you can find out why it failed using `GetLastError()`. (Always read the API documentation to find out what the function returns, and then **check that return value**.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `LoadString()` is failing (you should check its return value and `GetLastError()`). It fails if you call it in `DllMain()`. `DllMain()` is called while the loader-lock is held, therefore  significant restrictions are imposed on the functions that can be called within `DllMain()`.

According to MSDN:

[Dynamic-Link Library Best Practices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn633971.aspx)

> You should never perform the following tasks from within DllMain:
>   ...
>   •Call functions in User32.dll or Gdi32.dll. Some functions load another DLL, which may not be initialized.

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms647486.aspx) for `LoadString()` shows that it is a User32.dll function.

The way to fix this:

1. remove the `LoadString()` call from `DllMain()`.
2. have a function in your DLL which will load and return the string on-demand.

Comment: If I do create another function, how would I go on about passing the HINSTANCE?

Comment: The last error prints 714 by the way using `printf("LAST ERROR %X\n", GetLastError());`. `printf("LAST ERROR %X\n", LoadString(/*too lazy to type parameters*/));` returns `LAST ERROR 0`. **NOTE** these outputs are returned when running the code **outside** of DllMain with HINSTANCE stored in a variable

Comment: In DllMain store hinstDLL in a global variable when fdwReason is DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, then use it as usual. LoadString return value 0 means it did not find the string resource. So check if the .dll file actually contains the string. Also what does GetLastError() return?

Comment: Did you call GetLastError() immediately after LoadString?
E.g.:
result = LoadString(...)
error = GetLastError()

Comment: GetLastError() returns 714, as mentioned above, and yes I call it immediately after LoadString(). THe DLL does contain the string though (Hex Editor says so)

Comment: Are you really sure the resources are build into your .dll (during a rebuild something like `Compiling resources...` is printed)? Error code `0x714=1812="The specified image file did not contain a resource section."`. Additionally I quickly tried calling `LoadString(..)` from within `DllMain(..)` and it succeeded.